# How to link to other module's library in CMake/Android NDK?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, linker

I have 2 Android NDK modules, A and B. B depends on A, but cannot be integrated together, since B is only compatible with Android 8.1+ and needs another Android target when building.

I use CMake to build both.

How can I link B to A when building B?

I don't want to manually specify a relative path to somewhere in the `../.../../build/intermediates/cmake/[..]`.

```
add_library( A SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(A PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../A/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/${ANDROID_ABI}/libA.so )

target_link_libraries(B A)
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The supported path for doing this is to have all your native projects in one module. I know that doesn't meet your requirements, but wanted to clarify that no, there isn't really a "right" way to do what you're asking.

Being able to do have inter-module dependencies for native code is https://issuetracker.google.com/120166563. Once that's fixed you can do what you actually want.

What you have is probably the best choice for now given your requirements. I'm not that familiar with the Android Gradle API, but you might be able to get the out directory for A from the build.gradle for B and pass that to CMake as an argument. I think you could use https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.CmakeOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.CmakeOptions:buildStagingDirectory for this.